# Excel Line Tools Line

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image][][2]Is there a way to make the line so that the width/thickness scales as you change the size. At the moment if I draw a shape with the line tool and and then reduce the size of the shape the width of the line doesn't change. In the image Excel behaves like the first No Scaling set of images.

Comment: any printscreen (of before n after) ?

Comment: Why should the line width change with the size? The line width is a property of the shape and not tied to the shape size, thankfully. Because that would be really ugly.

Comment: @p._phidot_ Draw a shape. That's the before. Resize the shape. That's the after.

Comment: @teylyn I mis-read your earlier comment I actually disagree with it, by not scaling with the image size it can make the width disproportionate. There should be a scaling option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

owh.. that is your goal..(the prinscreen share upon request in comment). Now I get it.. (thanks for the print screen).. I had tried what you suggest.. and it happens as it did..

Method :

The feature you are looking for is straightforwardly achievable by.. (Method1) you paste the (line box) in Ms Paint, then re-scaling it there.

Non-straightforwardly, you may (Method2).. In ms office (excel or powerpnt), is to draw a set of 4 boxes (replacing the 4 lines, same width/length..) > group it > then scale as you need.

The result will be the very similar (just the scale differs).

Description :

Line is a 2D object that don't have volume.. there are not suppose to (mathematically) have a area/volume (only length). In computer or graph paper.. the weight/thickness is defined by the pen/pixel used to draw them. That's why it doesn't change in volume when you stretch/scale/resize it. Only it's length changes, not weight/thickness. Thus, I propose to replace the line with something with area/volume (the 4 thin boxes shape method) OR make every dot in the line to have a volume of its own (the MsPaint method). Any similar trick will work just as fine.

Hope it helps. ( :

Answer (score 0):

Your examples screenshots are a bit extreme. A shape by default has a much narrower outline than in your screenshot when it is created. You need to change the outline width to get it to the proportions you are showing.

Therefore, you may as well get the shape to the desired size first, and **after that** define the outline width.

As of now, Excel does not have a setting to scale the outline width when the shape is resized. You may want to suggest that as a new idea at http://excel.uservoice.com. If it gets sufficient votes, it will move to the top of the priorities list for new Excel features.

Edit: from your comment I can see that what you really need is a bitmap. A shape is a vector graphic and is designed to keep the outline the same width when the shape is resized.

What you can do without leaving Excel is

- draw the shape in the desired size
- set the desired outline width
- select the shape and use the "Copy as Picture" command from the Copy drop-down in the home ribbon. Accept the defaults of the dialog.
- paste the copied shape
- resize the pasted copy.

[image]

The smaller image in the following screenshot is the pasted copy resized.

[image]

Comment: I am creating an icon that will be used at various sizes, otherwise yes I would get it to the right-ish size and then set the line size.

Comment: A shape is a vector graphic. You want a bitmap, not a vector graphic. So, you're using the wrong tool for your purpose. Don't blame the hammer if you can't turn a screw with it.

Comment: I added a description to my answer of how you can solve your problem without leaving Excel. You can still change the accepted answer if that method suits you better..